# Symfony2 lazy loading doesn't work

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, lazy-loading

I have a problem with lazy loading in symfony2/doctrine2. 
I have a normal object (for example: type item) and this object has an id. If I look at the object at runtime I see that the id is set. Every other parameters like icon and amount are empty. I know, this is how lazy loading works but when I call the getters (getIcon) nothing happens. The icon attribute is still empty. I also tried to call the __load method but it doesn't help.

Sorry, forgot the code

```
class Character {
  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   */
  protected $id;
  /**
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Entity\Item", mappedBy="character")
   */
  protected $item;

  /*********************************************************************
   * Custom methods
   */

  public function getItem() {
      return $this->item;
  }
}
```

And this is the object where the lazy loading not works.

```
class Item {
  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   */
  protected $id;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   */
  protected $amount;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="string")
   */
  protected $icon;
}
```

EDIT2:

Constructor of character class

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->item = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some code ?

Comment: Sorry. I updated my post. If you need something specific tell me

Comment: where is character in item entity?

Comment: I have an character object and make an getItem to become the item object. Everything fine till this moment. Every calls on the item object wont work

Comment: the OneToMany relation is a 'new ArrayCollection();' in the constructor?

Comment: Yes. There is one attribute with manytoone and it doesnt work too.

Comment: please, post also entity constructors.

Comment: try adding fetch param on the relation's annotation. See the  [doc] (http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#onetomany)

Comment: chose the properly OneToMany association following the [doctrine2 docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#association-mapping) and you'll see lazy loading then works

Comment: the owning side of a OneToMany have to be always the "Many" side and needs to be bidirectional (like your case).

Comment: i updated my post with the constructor. I tried it with the fetch param but nothing happens. I find out that, after i call getIcon on the item object the "initialiser" param from doctrine gets empty.

Comment: To resolve your issue you need a bidirectional OneToMany [like described in the docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional). PS: and you need a character property of course

Answer (score 0):

So what the previos comments to your initial post are pointing at, is, that you need to implemend a ManyToOne relation in your Item entity to get all your stuff working.

In yout Character Entity you have this lines of code

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Entity\Item", mappedBy="character")
*/
protected $item;
```

This says you have a relation to an Entity Item which mappes the relation in the attribute "character". In this attribute the relation is stored. If you look into the database, you won't find any stored relations, because you class Item does not have the described mapping attribute character. Like gp_sflover pointed out, a OneToMany relations needs to be Bidirectional an required a ManyToOne relation in the "owning" side. So what you have to do is, add the following code to your Item Entity

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Entity\Character", inversedBy="item")
*/
protected $character;
```

The inversedBy attribute creates a bidirectional relation. Without this statement, you wouldn't be able to load getItems from your Character entity.

If you have changed your code you have to update your database and to restore the elements. After this, everything will work fine.